# price labels of the support and resistance levels are not showing in the right place

Tags: plot, pine-script

Edit to include picture of what I wanted.

[the long arrows show where the labels should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZkQi.png)

My label.new code is not behaving the way I want it to, namely, printing the labels above/below the resistance/support levels.

I've tried

`label.new(bar_index, top1, tostring(top1), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_labeldown, color=color.red, size=size.small)`

But that xloc is not right, while it compiles, it shows all the labels on the current candle.

```
study(title="srlabel", overlay=true)

 //code from [RS] support and resistance indicator

window1 = input(title='lookback window 1', type=input.integer, defval=8)
window2 = input(title='lookback window 2', type=input.integer, defval=21)

top1 = valuewhen(high >= highest(high, window1), high, 0)
bot1 = valuewhen(low <= lowest(low, window1), low, 0)
top2 = valuewhen(high >= highest(high, window2), high, 0)
bot2 = valuewhen(low <= lowest(low, window2), low, 0)

//this is what I've added to show the price of the s/r levels

label.new(bar_index, top1, tostring(top1), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_labeldown, color=color.red, size=size.small)

label.new(bar_index, bot1, tostring(bot1), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_labelup, color=color.blue, size=size.small)

//plots

t1 = plot(top1, color=top1 != top1[1] ? na : color.red, linewidth=1, title="")
b1 = plot(bot1, color=bot1 != bot1[1] ? na : color.blue, linewidth=1, title="")
t2 = plot(top2, color=top2 != top2[1] ? na : color.red, linewidth=1, title="")
b2 = plot(bot2, color=bot2 != bot2[1] ? na : color.blue, linewidth=1, title="")

fill(t1, t2, transp=80, color=color.red, title="")
fill(b1, b2, transp=80, color=color.blue, title="")
```

I wanted to show the labels above and below their respective price candles. I think the solution all lies with that xloc specification.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This prints your labels only when the levels change:

```
if change(top1)
    label.new(bar_index, top1, tostring(top1), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_labeldown, color=color.red, size=size.small)

if change(bot1)
    label.new(bar_index, bot1, tostring(bot1), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_labelup, color=color.blue, size=size.small)
```

[image]

[EDIT 2019.09.23 20:39 — LucF]
Perhaps this is closer to what you are looking for then:

```
if change(top2)
    label.new(bar_index, top2, tostring(top2), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_labeldown, color=color.red, size=size.small)

if change(bot2)
    label.new(bar_index, bot2, tostring(bot2), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_labelup, color=color.blue, size=size.small)
```

[image]

Comment: hey Luc, Thank you for the comment. But this doesn't work for me as shown on this screencap. https://imgur.com/cc1bbay How do you put the xloc where it found the top1 or bot1 prices? it seems like what i tried should do it but i'm missing something.

Comment: As is now shown in the chart accompanying my answer, the labels now print only when `bot1` or `top1` change, which is what I suppose you mean when you say you want them *where it found the top1 or bot1 prices*. If that's not what you need, explain it better because I don't see what else you want.

Comment: edited the OP to include a picture of what it should look like. arrows show places where the labels should be located

Comment: Edited answer with mods.